# How do you iterate over Points in a Polygon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, shapely

I have created a Polygon using the `sympy.geometry` package as below:

```
poly1 = Polygon((39.,4.), (32.,30.), (40.,10.), (42.,10.), (43.,14.))
```

The points of the Polygon are lon/lat co-ordinates.
I now want to project the polygon onto an ellipsoid (the Earth) and calculate the area of the polygon.

I have written the following code:

```
from pyproj import Proj

#specify projection for the Earth using reference ellipsoid"
wgs84=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
poly1_transformed=[]

for point in poly1:

    new_point = wgs84(point)
    poly1_transformed.append(new_point)
```

However I cannot iterate over the points in the Polygon. Is there any way to do so or an alternative method such that I can project the whole polygon (and eventually calculate the area) ?

This is my error:

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-0c7501bb5894> in <module>()
  5 wgs84=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
  6 
 ----> 7 for point in poly1:
  8     new_point = wgs84(point)
  9     print (point, new_point)

 TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the points by using `poly1.args` instead, since `Polygon` objects aren't iterable:

```
for point in poly1.args:
    new_point = wgs84(point)
    poly1_transformed.append(new_point)
```